# How can I create a Chrome mobile like menu animation?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Chrome mobile got this beautiful menu animation using Google's material design:

Chrome's menu in action: [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6DIGs.gif)

The cool thing is the way the menu's items open in order. Using CSS, jQuery or both, What would be the most correct way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSS only:

http://jsfiddle.net/coma/obeqs75k/

**CSS**

```
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400);

html {
    font-family: Roboto;
}

menu {
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    right: 10px;
    display: block;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
}

menu div.links a {
    display: block;
    padding: 18px;
}

menu div.icons > * {
    display: block;
    float: right;
    width: 52px;
    height: 52px;
    background: red;
}

menu div.icons:after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    clear: both;
}

menu > div {
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 52px;
    height: 52px;
    transition: all 350ms;
}

menu > div:after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 52px;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 0, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 10%,#fff 100%);
    opacity: 1;
    transition: top 500ms;
    transition-delay: 250ms;
}

#toggle {
    display: none;
}

#toggle:checked + div {
    width: 286px;
    height: 520px;
}

#toggle:checked + div:after {
    top: 100%;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<menu>
    <input type="checkbox" id="toggle"/>
    <div>
        <div class="icons">
            <label for="toggle"></label>
        </div>
        <div class="links">
            <a>New tab</a>
            <a>New incognito tab</a>
            <a>Bookmarks</a>
            <a>Recent tabs</a>
            <a>History</a>
            <a>Print...</a>
            <a>Request Desktop site</a>
            <a>Settings</a>
            <a>Help & Feedback</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</menu>
```